# Any known methods limit issues in Google Play services 9.4?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been using Play services 9.0, when I bumped the version to 9.4 it added additional 5874 methods with no changes from my app's code.

Do we have any known issues in 9.4 and is there any known workaround to reduce the method count of 9.4?

Answer (score 0):

For information with regard to Google Play Services v9.4, check the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

About the method count, try to read [this article](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/android-developer-heres-what-google-play-services-adds-to-your-method-count/) may help you. Google will (and should) continue to provide app developers with as many enrichments as possible (with the option to use only some of them), I advise you to only use the packages you truly need for your app.